# Why is Coursier needed? What is the different between coursier and maven, sbt, gradle?

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt, coursier

The documentation says that coursier is a new artifact manager for scala. But what is the difference between Coursier and build tools like maven, sbt and gradle? Why do I need `+1` folder with jar files? I have already `.m2` for maven repository, `.gradle` for gradle, and `.sbt` for sbt. So I built some project and now I have `AppData/Local/Coursier` with "same" jar files. Could somebody explain what is the goal for `Coursier` project?

Answer (score 6):

You are confusing a build tool like **sbt** and **Maven** and **Gradle** and **Ant**, with an artifact manager like **coursier** and **ivy**.

AFAIK *(please correct me if wrong)*, before **coursier** was invented, **sbt** used **ivy** to download the JAR files from repositories like **MavenCentral**.
After that, **coursier** was invented to be both faster and better handle **Scala** dependencies *(the versions suffixes and all that)*. I am not really sure what are the technical differences, but I really don't care since it is an implementation detail.
Then, newer versions of **sbt** simply switched from using **ivy** to use **coursier**, and the biggest difference was that it was now faster at downloading things, and that the cache folder changed.

With time, over the **coursier** bare artifact manager, other things have been built like the `cs` tool, `scala-cli`, the **GithubActions** shared actions like `coursier/setup-scala` & `coursier/cache`.
Thus, as of today, everything works together seamlessly.

About the duplicated JAR's folders.
Unless you are using both **sbt** and **maven** with shared dependencies between both, you should be able to just delete the old `.m2` folder.